# Build UI Component Library VUE

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, vue-router, uicomponents

I’m creating a library of components with vue. The real question is how to create documentation. It is more correct to create a docs folder and then create a new project (for example in nuxt), or have only one package.json in the root and then instantiate in the docs folder a new createApp with vue? The components I create in the library text them directly in the creation of documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [VitePress](https://vitepress.vuejs.org/) to build docs for your component library.

You can refer to this GitHub repo for inspiration: [Anu](https://github.com/jd-solanki/anu)

Docs Demo: [Anu](https://anu-vue.netlify.app/)